# Variables for many subroutines: code clean up

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables, subroutine

I've been thinking and searching for quite a few hours for a solution, but couldn't come up with the answer to my basic problem (obviously hard for me):

So I have many subroutines:

```
Sub OUTPUT()

Call CompañiasCubiertas
Call RangosDatos
Call EERR
Call Balance
Call Flujo
Call Indicadores
Call FormatoEERR
Call FormatoBalance
Call FormatoFlujo
Call FormatoIndicadores

End Sub
```

In each of this subs, I have many variables and workbooks declaration that are repeated:

```
Dim y As Workbook
Dim x As Workbook

Dim rangoi As Integer
Dim rangof As Integer
Dim compañia As String
Dim oipf As Integer
Dim ogpf As Integer 
Dim ogp As Integer 
Dim Fechai As Long
Dim Fechaf As Long
Dim Fechaper1 As Long
Dim Fechaper2 As Long


Set y = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set x = Application.Workbooks.Open("G:\Estudios\Biblioteca\Mercado Accionario Chileno\BBDD Oficial.xlsm")

compañia = y.Sheets("Información Financiera").Range("A3")

'Definir rangos para buscar los datos

Fechai = y.Sheets("Información Financiera").Range("C4").Value
Fechaf = y.Sheets("Información Financiera").Range("D4").Value
Fechaper1 = y.Sheets("Información Financiera").Range("C8").Value
Fechaper2 = y.Sheets("Información Financiera").Range("D8").Value
rangoi = Application.Match(Fechai, y.Sheets("Información Financiera").Range("E2:E300"), 0) + 1
rangof = Application.Match(Fechaf, y.Sheets("Información Financiera").Range("E2:E300"), 0) + 1
```

So, how can I avoid to declare all of this variables and workbooks in ALL subs.
I've been trying what I read in almost every site:

```
Public rangoi As Integer
Public rangof As Integer
```

and so on.... But if I create these variables inside `OUTPUT()`, It throws an error, and Outside It won't be read when I start the macro.

I am missing something basic here.

I'm particularly interested in making the variable...

```
Dim compañia As String
 compañia = y.Sheets("Información Financiera").Range("A3")
```

... usefull for all the subroutines, because I want to do a Loop over the variable `compañia` ( reseting it as an array of strings ) and put a `for` in the `OUTPUT` subroutine as:

```
 Sub OUTPUT()
    For i=1 To UBound(compañia)

Call subs1 ' subs1(compañia) , meaning the value of compañia changes the value of subroutines
Call subs2 ' subs2(compañia)
Call subs3 ' subs3(compañia)

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Are your subroutines located in the same Worksheet or Modules?

Comment: Nop, I have a module for each subroutine.

Comment: If your code works, I'd warmly recommend you post it (not just snippets!) on [codereview.se], where VBA reviewers will address every single issue with your code, from indentation, naming and comments to performance and efficiency, and overall structure and design. There's nothing like getting other people's feedback on your code for learning things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get the code running, and fortunately I came up with a solution. Probably I did exactly what it shouldn't be done, or it's not recommended, but again  I didn't have time to think for a better solution. I'm just learning of the different type of variables (Public, private, within or out a module etc...), and trying to understand them. Thanks for your suggestion, but those codes where a little too advanced for me.

```
Public compañia2() As String
Public compañia As String 

Sub OUTPUT()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'To avoid screen flickering
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Mensajes de alertas desactivado

CompañiasCubiertas
RangosDatos

For i = 1 To UBound(compañia2)
compañia = compañia2(i)
EERR
Balance
Flujo
Indicadores
FormatoEERR
FormatoBalance
FormatoFlujo
FormatoIndicadores

Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'To avoid screen flickering
End Sub

Sub CompañiasCubiertas()

'Other code for declaration of variables and other stuff

ReDim compañia2(x.Sheets.Count - 3 + 1) ' Define lenght of the array

For i = 1 To x.Sheets.Count - 2
compañia2(i) = y.Sheets("CompañiasCubiertas").Range("A" & i + 2).Value ' Fill array
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You *have* to create a public variable outside a subroutine, which is why you get an error when you attempt to declare it within a subroutine. When you declare a public variable, it is visible to all the subroutines - and it will be created at the point you start running your macro. The fact that it is declared outside a subroutine doesn't mean that the declaration won't happen.

Note that you can also declare a variable outside a subroutine using "Dim" (instead of Public) but such variables will be visible only to subroutines within the same module. Public variables will be visible to all routines in all modules.

Another approach to consider is to pass your widely needed variables as parameters. e.g. declare them in your main routine and then pass them to the subroutines needing them. This is often preferable to having lots of public variables but both approaches have their uses.

Edit: Added in response to Jules' comment.
Jules raises a very good point -  believe a "Public" variable in a worksheet code block is not truly public but only visible to all the routines in that worksheet. However, a public declaration in a module is truly Public.

Comment: A `Public` variable in a worksheet module *is* public. It's just that a worksheet happens to be an *object*, so that public variable is actually a public *instance field*, which means it can only be accessed from an instance of the class. A `Public` variable in a standard code module is otherwise known as a "global variable", and usually considered a bad practice.

Comment: @Mat's Mug. Ha! Thanks for the clear explanation.That makes perfect sense. I'd always assumed using "Global" to declare a variable in code module was just an old-fashioned way of declaring "Public". But it seems it's a bit more subtle than that.

Comment: The `Global` keyword was indeed superseded by `Public` and is deemed obsolete, as is the `Call` keyword for method calls, and the `Let` keyword for value assignments. So your assumption is correct - I meant "global" as "visible across the entire project", not `Global` (the obsolete keyword) ;-)

Comment: I was going to suggest creating a public type with all the variables.  So he declare the variable in one line.  Safer than using global/public variables.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can declare a public custom type in a module and only use one line to declare locally.  This solution is safer than using global variables.

```
Module1.bas

Public Type CustomType
    y As Workbook
    x As Workbook
    compania as String '<-- I don't have accent on my machine.
    rangoi As Integer
    rangof As Integer
    oipf As Integer
    ogpf As Integer
    ogp As Integer
    Fechai As Long
    Fechaf As Long
    Fechaper1 As Long
    Fechaper2 As Long
End Type

Module2.bas

Public Sub Sub1()
   dim lCustom as CustomType

   set lCustom.x = ActiveWorkBook '<-- just a sample
   lCustom.loipf = 1
End Sub

Module3.bas

Public Sub Sub2()
   dim lCustom as CustomType

   set lCustom.x = ActiveWorkBook '<-- just a sample
   lCustom.loipf = 1
End Sub
```